# Send form through GET and rewrite the URL

Tags: html

```
<form method=\"GET\" action=\"http://www.$domain/search/\">
<input type=\"search\" id=\"search\" name=\"search\" value=\"terms\">
</form>
```

This will send the form to this URL:
`http://www.$domain/search/?search=terms`

But what if I want a more SEO friendly URL instead?
Like this:
`http://www.$domain/search/terms`

Is it possible to do without losing support for older browsers?

Comment: Use htaccess. This will help http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible if you want to use javascript.

First you need to move input outside of form. Then put an onchange event like this :

```
<input type=\"search\" id=\"search\" name=\"search\" value=\"terms\" onchange=\"myFunction(this.value)\">
```

Then you need to put an id for the form so that we can identify it

```
<form method=\"GET\" id=\"myForm\">
```

And write the myFunction in Javascript :

```
myFunction(value) {
   document.getElementById('myForm').action = "http://www.$domain/search/"+value;
}
```